# Ouput loop contents twice in one loop?

Tags: wordpress

I'm really stuck on what to search for to get a start on this.

I want to be able to output 2 posts in one loop, so I can DIV wrapping 2 posts at one time...

What I've done below is just pure example - i'm trying to explain what I need it to do.
If any knows a way or where I can find a tutorial, that would be awesome! Thanks.

**THE LOOP**

Thanks to @Rob for helping me get this far, but it seems to output duplicates weirdly...

```
<?php $latest = new WP_Query(array(

    'category_name'  => 'news',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 6

)); ?>

<?php $i = 0; if ( $latest->have_posts()) : while ($latest->have_posts()) : $latest->the_post(); ?>

    <?php $odd = ++$i % 2; ?>

    <?php if($odd) : ?>
    <div class="dual-post-wrapper">
    <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <?php the_content(); ?>

        </div>

    <?php if(!$odd) : ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; unset($latest); endif; ?>
```

**THE OUT PUTTED HTML**

This is what the outputted HTML is looking like - for some reason it is duplicating post 1,2,3 and 4??? Weird!

```
<div class="dual-post-wrapper">

    <div class="post-1">

        Post 1 Content

    </div>

    <div class="post-2">

        Post 2 Content

    </div>

</div>

<div class="dual-post-wrapper">

    <div class="post-3">

        Post 3 Content

    </div>

    <div class="post-4">

        Post 4 Content

    </div>

</div>

<div class="dual-post-wrapper">

    <div class="post-5">

        Post 5 Content

    </div>

    <div class="post-6">

        Post 6 Content

    </div>

</div>

<div class="dual-post-wrapper"> <!-- these are duplicates?? -->

    <div class="post-1">

        Post 1 Content

    </div>

    <div class="post-2">

        Post 2 Content

    </div>

</div>

<div class="dual-post-wrapper"> <!-- these are duplicates?? -->

    <div class="post-3">

        Post 3 Content

    </div>

    <div class="post-4">

        Post 4 Content

    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple counter and modulus.

```
<?php $i = 0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $odd = ++$i % 2; ?>

    <?php if($odd) : ?>
        <div class="dual-post-wrapper">
    <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                         <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

    <?php if(!$odd) : ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

That should work if you always have an even number of posts. You should probably count the number of posts before hand and close the div `if(!$odd || $last)`

Comment: Thank you Rob, much appreciated for your help - I tried your code (which I have update my post above), but for some reason it's duplicating the first four posts. So its outputting 5 dual-post-wrappers when it should technically only be outputting 3? This is what it should be displaying 1+2 3+4 5+6 but its outputting this... 1+2 3+4 5+6 1+2 3+4 ...strange?? Thanks Rob

Comment: I'm such a douche, ignore me - it was my jquery creating the dupes. Worked perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has built in functions for counting the loop and rewinding the post.

To count you loop use:

```
//Create a custom query var:

$displayposts = new WP_Query(); 

//start loop with it
<?php if ($displayposts->have_posts()) :while ($displayposts->have_posts()) : $displayposts->the_post();

//count it
$count_id = $displayposts->current_post + 1; 

//loop stuff <?php endwhile; else:?>

//rewind the post 
rewind_posts();
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts

Comment: Thanks @Wyck but I cant see how this would work for me - I cant envisage where to put the dual-post-wrapper div that wraps the two posts - the codex doesn't have much examples for a beginners like me.